# Escaping a CSS selector

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

I've escaped a CSS selector like so:

```
$('#a\\[b\\]-c')
```

The `[` and `]` aren't valid characters, so I escaped them with [2 slashes](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). Seems to work just fine, but one of my clients is reporting that something isn't working on that page in IE7, and I can't reproduce it.

Is this escaping handled by jQuery internally, or does it delegate it back to the browser, and maybe their version of the browser isn't handling it correctly?

That's all I can think of....everything else looks fine.

Can't show source unfortunately.

Comment: could we see the site or a demo?

Comment: So your attribute is id="a[b]-c" ?

Comment: the first of the two slashes will be removed by javascript, the remaining slash will be the only one jquery sees.   jquery will see this: `$('#a\[b\]-c')`

Comment: These selectors are part of the CSS 2.1 specification.

Comment: @Gisili: Oh, they are part of the spec? That's good to know. Thanks!

Comment: @Joseph: No. It's a closed down site with confidential information. Can't make a demo because I can't reproduce the problem myself :\

Comment: @Johnny: Right. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That escaping is correct. The following will successfully target the `<div>`.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('#a\\[b\\]-c').innerText)
```

```html
<div id="a[b]-c">target me</div>
```